# How to interact with the activity beneath the top dialog activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have a dialog activity staying in the top of a screen but only covering a small portion of it. I know in the normal situation I am not allowed to manipulate the activity under the top one like click some buttons even though I can see it. But I really need this ability.
Below is part of my code:

```
    private void onPlayStreamingClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), LivePlayerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("cache", false);
    intent.putExtra("loop", false);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The theme of LivePlayerActivity is "Theme.Dialog" and it does not cover the full screen. So I want to click the buttons in the activity behind LivePlayerActivity which could be seen from the screen. I know according to the essential mechanism of android lifecycle, after started LivePlayerActivity, the activity contains above code will change to pause status so it is not going to react to any touch or click events from the user. But I was told there is a way to make this happen and I want to know how. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: very hard to tell what you're doing without you posting some code. But I guess you can do it via interfaces as listeners

Comment: I want to interact with an activity behind another activity which only covering a small part of the screen.

Comment: At least show some work that you have done.

Comment: @Ghulam Moinul Quadir, I have added a code snippet now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not "modify" the underlying activity behind a dialog directly, or while the dialog is open. You have some options:

- Make the changes just before showing the dialog
- Use dialog callbacks (e.g. onDialogShowed), or the button ones.

Comment: I does not mean interacting an activity behind a dialog but an activity.

Comment: Do you mean the activity that launched the dialog, right? (can't be another way)

Comment: No. Its not a dialog. Its an activity with its theme set as "Theme.Dialog".

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html  try getWindow().clear and set flags